# How to apply multiple masks to an array and count occurrences per row

Tags: python, numpy, count

Let's say I have a 2D array with positive integers:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 1, 2],
                 [1, 2, 5],
                 [1, 3, 6],
                 [3, 3, 3],
                 [3, 4, 6],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                ])
```

and a threshold (positive integer). I want to count, for each row, how many ocurrences are `< threshold`, how many `>= threshold and < threshold+2`, and how many `>= threshold+2`. The results are to be stored on a size 3 x n array, where `n = a.shape[0]` and each of the 3 columns corresponds to the threshold partition.

For the example above and `threshold = 3`, it would be:

```
b = numpy.array([[3, 0, 0],
                 [2, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1],
                 [0, 3, 0],
                 [0, 2, 1],
                 [0, 1, 2],
                ])
```

My solution was to use a for loop combined with masks, so that I could apply the masks individually for each row. But using for loops on arrays feels wrong. Is there a more optimized way to accomplish that?

My solution so far:

```
b = []
for row in a:
    b.append((numpy.sum(row < threshold),
              numpy.sum((row >= threshold) * (row < threshold + 2)),
              numpy.sum(row >= threshold + 2)))
b = numpy.array(b)
```

Comment: [`np.ma.masked_where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html#numpy.ma.masked_where)

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: This weekend I'm going to review them in depth and adopt one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Making use of `elementwise comparison` against the thresholds and summing each row -

```
t = 3 # threshold
mask0 = (a<t)
mask2 = a>=t+2
mask1 = (a>=t) & ~mask2
out = np.c_[mask0.sum(1), mask1.sum(1), mask2.sum(1)]
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you think about it closely, we are creating three bins there. So, we could use get the bin ID for each element and finally, get the count of each row based on the IDs. We would use `np.searchsorted` to get those bin IDs and then elementwise equate and sum along each row.

Thus, we would have a solution, like so -

```
t = 3 # threshold
bins = [t, t+2]   # Create intervals
N = len(bins)+1   # Number of cols in output
idx = np.searchsorted(bins,a,'right') # Get bin IDs
out = np.column_stack([(idx==i).sum(1) for i in range(N)])
```

We can vectorize the last step with `broadcasting` -

```
out = (idx == np.arange(N)[:,None,None]).sum(2).T
```

And one more vectorized alternative, which would also be memory efficient with `np.bincount` -

```
M = a.shape[0]
r = N*np.arange(M)[:,None]
out = np.bincount((idx + r).ravel(),minlength=M*N).reshape(M,N)
```

Comment: I'm taking approach #1 because it's the one that seems more intuitive to me (given my current level of numpy familiarity). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to break points `3` and `5`.  We can use `np.searchsorted` to find where each element of `a` falls with respect to our break points.

- `np.searchsorted([3, 5], 1, side='right')` will return `0` because `1` should be inserted at position 0 to maintain sorted-ness.
- `np.searchsorted([3, 5], 3, side='right')` will return `1` because `3` can be inserted at position 0 or any other in which a value of `3` occupies to maintain sorted-ness.  The default behavior to insert to the left of elements that are equal.  We can change this to insert to the right of all elements that are equal.  This accounts for the condition `< threshold`
- `np.searchsorted([3, 5], 5)` will return `1`
- `np.searchsorted([3, 5], 7)` will return `2`
- I use `np.eye` to build sub arrays to sum over in order to count how many fall within each bin.

---

```
np.eye(3, dtype=int)[np.searchsorted([3, 5], a, side='right')].sum(1)

array([[3, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

---

We can generalize this with a function

```
def count_bins(a, threshold, interval_sizes):
    edges = np.append(threshold, interval_sizes).cumsum()
    eye = np.eye(edges.size + 1, dtype=int)
    return eye[edges.searchsorted(a, side='right')].sum(1)

count_bins(a, 3, [2])

array([[3, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Or

```
count_bins(a, 3, [1, 1])

array([[3, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

---

But I'd rather return a pandas dataframe to see things more clearly

```
def count_bins(a, threshold, interval_sizes):
    edges = np.append(threshold, interval_sizes).cumsum()
    eye = np.eye(edges.size + 1, dtype=int)
    labels = ['{:0.0f} to {:0.0f}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(np.append(-np.inf, edges), np.append(edges, np.inf))]
    return pd.DataFrame(
        eye[edges.searchsorted(a, side='right')].sum(1),
        columns=labels
    )

count_bins(a, 3, [2])

   -inf to 3  3 to 5  5 to inf
0          3       0         0
1          2       0         1
2          1       1         1
3          0       3         0
4          0       2         1
5          0       1         2
```

Comment: `eye` or broadcasting would be memory intensive. Figured out a better way with `bincount`.

Comment: @Divakar agreed